# An error in a program to calculate age in python

Tags: python

Hello everybody i wrote a simple program to calculate age in python i faced a problem that the result was uncorrect and i fixed it,but i want to know its reason,i'll put the code and it's a weak code,because i'm a newbie.

So why should i put variables(Day,Month,and Year) down if statements,while when they were up them the result was uncorrect? and thanks.

```
CrrentYear=input("Enter the current year in numbers : ")
CurrentMonth=input("Enter the current month in numbers : ")
CurrentDay=input("Enter the current day in numbers : ")
BirthYear=input("Enter your birth year in numbers : ")
BirthMonth=input("Enter your birth month in numbers : ")
BirthDay=input("Enter your birth day in numbers : ")


if CurrentDay < BirthDay:
    CurrentDay+=30
    CurrentMonth-=1

if CurrentMonth < BirthMonth:
   CurrentMonth+=12
   CrrentYear-=1

Day=CurrentDay-BirthDay
Month=CurrentMonth-BirthMonth
Year=CrrentYear-BirthYear



print("Your age is : "+str(Year)+" "+"Years"+" "+"and"+" "+str(Month)+"     "+"Months"+" "+"and"+" "+str(Day)+" "+"Days")
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, this assumes that every month is 30 days. Other than that, I'm not totally clear on what you're asking.

Comment: What does "up if statements" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague... but I will try to help.

By "up if statements" I think you mean *above* the `if` statements, and by "down if statements" I think you mean *below* the `if` statements.

If you calculate `Day`, `Month` and `Year` *above* the `if` statements, sometimes the code will still work, depending on the inputs. This is because your first `if` statements *only* happen IF `currentDay` is less than `birthDay`.

In my case, my birthday is on the 1st, so that `if` statement returns `False`, so the result is ok: you don't need to round the day and month (yet).

However, if the current day was `20` and the birthday was `10`, you can't have `-10` days, so you have to **add one month**, and recalculate how many days it was.

The same kind of logic applies to the months & years.

Comment: Yes. Code is executed top to bottom, generally. Sometimes you can define functions below (and call them above) but for regular statements, the flow is top to bottom. In your case, you are modifying values inside your `if` statements, so those modifications must happen first!